# Struggling with the eclipse tutorial on helloworld

Tags: eclipse

hey guys, i am completely new to programming but I am trying hard, however the tutorial for a helloworld application on eclipse is bugged im sure either that or im being stupid.

when it gets to the stage where i am creating my helloworld class, i select HelloWorld/src as requested but then it says enter helloworld as the class name which i do but when it says select the checkbox to create main() method, there is no such check box there.
the checkboxes there are:
public
default
abstract
final

then it says which method stubs would you like to create?
public static void main(string[]args)
constructors from super class
inherited abstract methods

I notice it says main once in all of them check boxes but never main()

please dont slate this question i really need help and this is the place to get it i believe.
kindest of regards
paul

Comment: @paul Hi Paul, it's difficult to understand what exactly you're referring to in your question. You should zero in on exactly one question you have for the community and then attach a screenshot of where you are having trouble. [Directions for taking a screenshot](http://take-a-screenshot.org/).

Comment: @paul Also, you may want to consider NOT using an IDE like Eclipse if you are just starting out programming. Eclipse is great if you have a really big, complicated programming project ahead of you, but if you are just learning then all of its nifty features are probably just getting in the way--try just using a text editor!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paul, there's a good point by Chris W. that it is somewhat difficult to find the explicit question in your plea, but it sounds to me like you have a legitimate problem.

Your problem is that the doc is outdated. Eclipse has gone through many versions and the user interface has changed slightly between versions, while the doc has not always followed.

In your case, you need to click "generate the main(string[] args) method stub", or whichever checkbox most resembles that one.

To learn about the main() method in java, I suggest a java tutorial from its proprietor's pages, for example [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

Paul - they mean this:

Which method stubs would you like to create?

```
[] public static void main(String [] args)
```

This is the main entry point for the class, similar to main() in C, C++

Answer (score 0):

Do what I have done in the following picture.
Ignore the warning(i've already done that step).
Have fun coding.  :P

[image: "Hello World!" Main Class]